# connection and Toastbar not displaying issue

Tags: codenameone

1)ConnectionRequest using actionListener as parameter

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> responses;
public void groupConnection(StateMachine sm, ActionListener al) {
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> parsedData = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            responses = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) parsedData.get("root");
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    al.actionPerformed(null);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Exception err) {
           //System.out.println("handleException " + err);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleIOException(IOException err) {
           //toastbar doesnt work here but dialogBox works, if showForm("Groups") is used, toastbar is also shown along with dialogbox
           //ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Please check your network connection", 4000);
           //sm.showForm("Groups", null);
           Dialog.show("", "Please check your network connection", "ok", null);
        }
    };
    AllUrl allUrl = new AllUrl();
    connectionRequest.setUrl(allUrl.groupsMenu);
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    connectionRequest.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
}
```

In connectionRequest code above, if there is no network connection, it gives IoException: unreachable which is handled by handleIOException method below but if i use dialogBox there, it works. Instead toastbar doesnt work there, why is that? If I use showForm("Form",null) along with dialogBox and toastbar, the same form is called repeatedly and toastbar is also seen with dialog box appearing multiple times.

2)postForm(Form f) method

```
connectionGroup = new GroupConnection();
connectionGroup.groupConnection(StateMachine.this, new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
//checking connectionGroup.responses == null doesnt work since the connectionRequest gives IOException if no network.So Toastbar doesnt work here.
  if (connectionGroup.responses == null) {
      ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Please check your network connection", 4000);
  }
    if (connectionGroup.responses != null) {
        for (Map<String, Object> element : connectionGroup.responses) {
            String tableName = (String) element.get("name");
            TextArea nameLabel = new TextArea(tableName.toUpperCase());
            f.add(singleRowContainerr);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In postForm method above, I used to check if there is network connection or not by checking: if (connectionGroup.responses == null) { do smth...}, it doesnt work here since the connectionRequest gives IoException & doesnt run code inside connectionRequest.

How to solve this problem? I have to show "check connection" in toastBar and a label with text "no connection" as well. PS I need to put all my components & connectionRequest in postForm since I need to go to the form before connectionRequest is called.

Answer (score 0):

`ToastBar` is bound to a specific `Form` whereas `Dialog` will block any form to show itself.

You've set the `ToastBar` to one form then transitioned to another `Form`.